# removing image from posts pages but keep it on home page

Tags: wordpress

I'm making the website for my band, first time using wordpress.

I have an img after all my posts, it's nothing but horizontal line just to separate my posts on my home page, but it's look so gross on the end of post page...I want to keep that horisontal line at my home page(where my posts are), but when someone open the post page, i don't want it anymore.

I tried to use css display: none; for page id-s but i can't always add selectors in css when i posting something on website.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to check out the [`:last-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) Selector. Without seeing your site, I guess there is a line image at the bottom of each post. On the Home page, you have multiple posts, so the line separates the posts, but the line isn't needed on a single post page.

You could use the `:last-child` selector to reference the last image inside the content wrapper in order to add `display:none` to the last img inside that wrapper. That way, on the single post page, the line will disappear, and on the Home page, the line underneath the last post would also disappear. Something like:

```
.entry-content:last-child img {

    display:none;

}
```

There is also a [`:last-of-type`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp) Selector as well.

Just as an aside, unless it's very stylized, I wouldn't use an image just to draw a line. I would use a border to separate the various elements on the Home page. For example:

```
.blog .post, .archive .post {

    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding: 0 0 35px;
    margin: 0 0 35px;

}
```

Comment: <div class="hr_linePosts">
     <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/hr.png'" alt="Custom Hr Line">
    </div>

Comment: don't work for me , because i have only one picture that is under all of my posts and i hate it...

Comment: @StefanMitrovic I did a test based on your code above, and modified my original answer. Try this: .hr_linePosts:last-child img { .. }